# Customized PowerApps form not loading, OOTB default form still loading

Tags: powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have replaced the OOTB SharePoint list form with a Power App version by using the "Customize Form" option in the list ribbon. I'm able to make PA form changes and publish successfully, however, when opening an item in a list view by double-clicking or selecting the 'Edit' option in the ribbon, it still loads the OOTB default form. I have checked a number of setting and tried various steps to force it to load like:

1. Ensuring "Use a custom form created in PowerApps" is selected in form settings
2. Opened item in various browsers such as Chrome and Firefox
3. Selected "CTRL+F5" to hard refresh the page cache.

None of these have worked. I intially customized the list form when I created the list, ran into a slew of problem and decided to change the form setting back to using default OOTB and deleting the customized PA form. I then used the customize form setting again to create another PA form and now it will not load.